# Doctrine MongoDB ODM - bug with cascading executeUpsert

Tags: symfony, doctrine-mongodb

doctrine/mongodb-odm version 1.0.8

I have a document that uses self-referencing many to many bi-directional relationship. Ininitally I was getting errors telling me I must set up cascade=persist. I did that and now I am getting a very odd doctrine error. My document:

```
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as ODM;

/**
 * @ODM\Document(collection="ledger", repositoryClass="Tng\ExampleBundle\Repository\LedgerRepository")
 */
class Ledger
{
    /**
     * @ODM\Id(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * If this is a payment, this will link to the debit ledger
     * @ODM\ReferenceMany(
     *      targetDocument="Tng\ExampleBundle\Document\Ledger",
     *      inversedBy="payment",
     *      strategy="addToSet",
     *      cascade={"persist"},
     *      simple=true
     * )
     */
    protected $payment_for;

    /**
     * If this is a debit, these are the payments and credits
     * @ODM\ReferenceMany(
     *      targetDocument="Tng\ExampleBundle\Document\Ledger",
     *      mappedBy="payment_for",
     *      strategy="addToSet",
     *      cascade={"persist"},
     *      simple=true
     * )
     */
    protected $payments;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->payments = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->payment_for = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    // all standard getters/setters with:
    public function addPaymentFor(\Tng\ExampleBundle\Document\Ledger $paymentFor)
    {
        $this->payment_for[] = $paymentFor;
        $paymentFor->payments[] = $this;
    }

    public function removePaymentFor(\Tng\ExampleBundle\Document\Ledger $paymentFor)
    {
        $this->payment_for->removeElement($paymentFor);
        $paymentFor->payments->removeElement($this);
    }
}
```

Now when I try to save the cascading records:

```
$payment->setPaymentFor($ledger);
$dm->persist($payment);
```

I get the following error:

> Notice: Undefined index: $set
>
> Stack Trace
>
> 1. in vendor/doctrine/mongodb-odm/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Persisters/DocumentPersister.php at line 315   -
> 2. at ErrorHandler ->handleError ('8', 'Undefined index: $set', '/var/www/etc-mongo-tng/vendor/doctrine/mongodb-odm/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Persisters/DocumentPersister.php', '315', array('data' => array(), 'options' => array('upsert' => true)))
> 3. in vendor/doctrine/mongodb-odm/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Persisters/DocumentPersister.php at line 315   +
>      at DocumentPersister ->executeUpsert (array(), array())
> 4. in vendor/doctrine/mongodb-odm/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Persisters/DocumentPersister.php at line 296   +
> 5. at DocumentPersister ->executeUpserts (array()) 
>      in vendor/doctrine/mongodb-odm/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/UnitOfWork.php at line 1189   +
> 6. at UnitOfWork ->executeUpserts (object(ClassMetadata), array('000000005a8560de00007fc48349ed60' => object(Ledger)), array()) 
>      in vendor/doctrine/mongodb-odm/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/UnitOfWork.php at line 425   +

It doesn't look like the same bug affects the 1.1.2 branch. If I patch DocumentPersister.php as follows, it all works. Is this is a legitimate bug? Should I make a PR?

```
private function executeUpsert(array $data, array $options)
{
    // I added this line
    if (empty($data)) { return; }
    $options['upsert'] = true;
    $criteria = array('_id' => $data['$set']['_id']);
    unset($data['$set']['_id']);
```